# RMPolylineAnnotation not appearing on map (mapbox)

Tags: ios, mapbox, route-me

I'm trying to add an RMPolylineAnnotation to my mapbox map but for some reason it's not appearing. I'm not sure if I'm missing a call or a function that's used in the drawing process. The code I'm using to add it is below:

```
for (id key in dFeatures)
        {
            RMPolylineAnnotation *polylineAnnotation = [[RMPolylineAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:self.rmMapView points:[dFeatures objectForKey:key]];
            [polylineAnnotation setLineWidth:10.0f];
            [polylineAnnotation setLineColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

            [self.rmMapView addAnnotation:polylineAnnotation];
        }
```

dFeatures is just a dictionary which contains numerous arrays of points used in the initialisation of my RMPolylineAnnotations, see below:

```
(lldb) po dFeatures
{
    "Blacka_trail_a" =     (
        "<-1.58483448,+53.32148646> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58471249,+53.32137547> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58458351,+53.32126949> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58444752,+53.32116250> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58430553,+53.32103852> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58421054,+53.32094053> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58407455,+53.32084955> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58395256,+53.32076356> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58385757,+53.32067257> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58368158,+53.32054159> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58351160,+53.32040561> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58338261,+53.32028262> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58326062,+53.32017964> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58312563,+53.32006065> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58298264,+53.31996566> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58288065,+53.31986368> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58275166,+53.31976469> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58265767,+53.31965771> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58244669,+53.31949373> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58233870,+53.31939874> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58225070,+53.31930475> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58210072,+53.31921777> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58199972,+53.31908678> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58185674,+53.31899580> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58177574,+53.31893480> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58172075,+53.31897880> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58167276,+53.31901980> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58156977,+53.31901980> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58146679,+53.31904380> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58137080,+53.31906379> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58127481,+53.31910879> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58114483,+53.31915279> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58098685,+53.31920178> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58085687,+53.31924278> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58075388,+53.31927878> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58059590,+53.31935577> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58044492,+53.31938777> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58032894,+53.31942477> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58028094,+53.31944077> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58020495,+53.31947376> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58018396,+53.31948576> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58025895,+53.31952676> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58035494,+53.31954775> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58044993,+53.31954375> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58051892,+53.31953975> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58064190,+53.31951975> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58075789,+53.31952075> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58088088,+53.31954075> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58092187,+53.31959474> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58092788,+53.31965973> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58100187,+53.31975472> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58108386,+53.31982871> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58108987,+53.31989370> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58110287,+53.31994670> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58119786,+53.32000069> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58125185,+53.32003368> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58132685,+53.32010367> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58134685,+53.32015667> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58141484,+53.32023866> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58146084,+53.32034164> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58152184,+53.32041963> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58148684,+53.32053362> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58151284,+53.32060761> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58151285,+53.32067260> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58149085,+53.32078359> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58148386,+53.32085258> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58146186,+53.32092657> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58146187,+53.32100857> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58141288,+53.32111455> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58144588,+53.32118454> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58145188,+53.32125854> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58143788,+53.32131553> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58154087,+53.32132353> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58168385,+53.32131253> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58182084,+53.32132452> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58193682,+53.32132552> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58208081,+53.32132552> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58229278,+53.32133451> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58241577,+53.32135151> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58257975,+53.32135251> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58272973,+53.32135651> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58278472,+53.32134851> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58291471,+53.32134950> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58304369,+53.32137050> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58318768,+53.32137450> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58339265,+53.32137149> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58350164,+53.32140049> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58365262,+53.32140049> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58380260,+53.32141348> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58391859,+53.32142248> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58410357,+53.32142248> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58422656,+53.32143947> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58436954,+53.32144847> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58455452,+53.32146547> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58465651,+53.32147446> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58471850,+53.32147846> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time",
        "<-1.58484048,+53.32148646> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/28/14, 11:07:56 AM Greenwich Mean Time"
    );
}
```

This all seems to load in fine and shows that I have a valid RMPolylineAnnotation if I set a breakpoint after it but nothing shows on the map. I have noticed this coming up in the lldb though:

```
2014-02-28 11:36:56.579 WildSheffield[7700:70b] -[<RMShape: 0xc13aee0> display]: Ignoring bogus layer size (397983.125000, 470151.031250)
```

I'm guessing this is the cause of the issue but I don't understand why the layer is coming out so large as my array of coordinates are all fairly closely placed.

Can anyone offer any advice on how to fix this issue? I have looked through the reference docs so much but can't seem to work out what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks

EDIT 1:

I have noticed that when I zoom in to the map I get the following error now:

> : CGContextPathContainsPoint: invalid context 0x0. This is a
>   serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an
>   invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation
>   of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

This could be the cause of the issue but I'm not sure why it would be happening as my route definitely falls within the map boundaries etc. Is there a library I haven't added potentially?

EDIT 2:

I have also noticed that although I am setting my rmMapView delegate this function is never called:

```
 - (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation
```

Does the RMPolylineAnnotation not count as an actual annotation (i.e. should it not call this method?), the for loop is definitely adding it to the '_visibleAnnotations' array in the RMMapView.

Comment: Were you able to fix your problem yet?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same error and it was caused by my code returning a line (RMShape *) that had zero length (i.e. P1 and P2 were the same point).  It seems that this caused some divide by zero issues in the layer rendering code.  My code was roughly as follows, and by adding the if() section, no more errors :-)

```
RMShape *path = [[RMShape alloc] initWithView:mapView];
CLLocation * p1 = _currentWayPoint.coord;
...
CLLocation * p2 = bisectLocation;

float bisectLength = [p1 distanceFromLocation:p2];
if (bisectLength == 0.0f)
{
    NSLog(@"Ignoring invalid bisect length %f", bisectLength);
    return nil;
}

[path moveToCoordinate:p1.coordinate];
[path addLineToCoordinate:p2.coordinate];
return path;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are adding an instance of a polyline for every point in your set, instead of one polyline that includes all of those points.

Comment: No sorry I should have been a bit clearer, the dictionary can contain multiple arrays. I use the key name to identify the different arrays, so as you can see this dictionary contains one key entry called 'Blacka_trail_a', and the [dFeatures objectForKey:key] accesses the array stored with this keyname. That's why I'm so confused by what's happening as I feel the rest of the code should be correct?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my original post with an error that gets displayed upon zoom, do you know why I would now be getting this error? Thanks.

Comment: I think I may be calling this in the wrong place, I currently have this code running in viewDidLoad, I'm guessing it needs to be called much later than this. Any advice as to where the code should be placed?